# Basic limit problem

Tags: calculus, limits

I can't really figure out how to solve this:

$$\lim\limits_{r \to 9} \frac{{\sqrt r}}{(r-9)^4}$$

Any ideas?

*Edit: For clarification, the reason I'm confused is that I get the idea that I would have to cancel out the r in the denominator since otherwise it'd be zero. I'm not sure how to do this (or even if I have to at all), so that's why I'm asking this

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: Any thoughts on this at all?

Comment: As $r$ goes to $9$ the numerator goes to 3 and the denominator goes to $0$ from the right.  So the limit is...?

Comment: What do you think the limit should be? Consider the denominator and numerator separately, how should the limits for them interact?

Comment: Oh, I see now! Because the denominator is raised to an even power, it only approaches from the right and thus is always positive. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The numerator goes to $3$ and the denominator goes to $0$, so we're looking at an infinity.

Then we need to look at the sign: The numerator is obviously positive  for the relevant $r$ (being close to $3$), and the denominator is positive because it's a fourth power. So in the end the result is $+\infty$.

Comment: Thanks Arthur! This was the most helpful response

Comment: @Kevin If the denominator had not been a fourth power, so that it was negative for $r$ below $9$ and positive for larger $r$, then the limit would've been undefined, since going from below and going from above gives different results.

Comment: Thanks, I see that now- the way I was thinking about it before was just entirely off track.